# what is a angular seed and Angular-Seed project for AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular and not clear with Angular seed.

I have some questions:

- what is angular seed?
- Is it necessary?
- How to use angular seed?

Sorry if something is wrong in the questions.

Answer (score 3):

Angular Seed is totally baked template for your rapid angular application development .

It has test suite like  [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) and [protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) and [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)
and many more . It has bower front-end tool manager  . And Grunt as task runner . You can update add and delete any node module whenever you want with `package.json`.

In a easy way , all you need to get in super fast way is ready in there . Hope you got your answer .

Answer (score 0):

Angular seed project can be seen as a template or kick-starter project that could be installed to get started with your `AngularJS` apps.
   Check out this link:

[Angular-Seed example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-hello-world-angular)